# ubuntu installation in virtual box

Tags: ubuntu

How to install ubuntu in virtual box?

I've done whole procedure, and now stuck at "ubuntu installation type" page, where I got option

( if you want to delete all data and install ubuntu.

or to choose or create your own partitions from option "Something Else)

If I choose something else then afterwards what steps I've to follow?

Answer (score 2):

If you choose "Something else", you will see a screen where you need to specify details for your new root, home and swap partition. You should dedicate at least 5GB for root/Home partition and at least 512MB for swap partition.

Anyway, considering you are installing Ubuntu in VirtualBox, I don't really see a reason to go for "something else". That options are mostly used for dual-boot systems (which you don't need in VB)

Best solution in VB is to dedicate dynamically allocated hard disc size in VB and just go for "Delete all and install Ubuntu"